# Is the XOR of PRGs sharing the same input a PRG?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

I have question in learning PRG. Given that $f$ and $f_1$ are PRGs, both $\{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^{2n}$.

Is $g(x) = f(x)$ xor $f_1(x)$ a PRG?

Someone told me that in this case, $g(x)$ is not a PRG, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Is $X$ the same as $x$? Assuming so, hint: exhibit a counterexample. More precisely, assume $f$ is a PRG, and exhibit a $f_1$ that is a PRG such that $g$ is not a PRG. You won't have to stretch your imagination.

Comment: Yes, $X$ is the same as $x$.

Comment: @fgrieu I know that if I want to prove it, I should give a counterexample, but I have no idea about how to choose a counterexample.

Comment: Hint: You need $f$ and $f_1$ to be related to each other for a counter example.

Comment: I was almost sure from the title that [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53521/is-the-xor-of-prg-outputs-a-prg) was a duplicate, but it's not. Looking at the differences between the two questions *might* help you think  of a counterexample, though.

Comment: I might get the point that when I choose a PRG $f$ and also PRG $f_1$ same with $f$, so $g$ will always output 0, so it definitely not a PRG

Comment: @Mkt: you nailed it. Perhaps, [answer your own question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)?

Comment: And if you really dislike $f=f_1$, you can also choose $f_1$ as $f$ with every output bit inverted, aka $f=f_1\oplus 1^{2n}$

Comment: For bonus points, show that if PRGs exist, then there are two PRGs $f,f_1$ such that $g$ is a PRG.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everybody's help. I have known that if $f$ and $f_1$ have some relation, then $g$ can not be PRG.
e.g. $f = f_1$, then we can know, after $f ⊕ f_1$, it always return 0 for $g(x)$, in this case, $g(X)$ will never be a PRG.